# Access pyhive through hive-site.xml properties

Tags: hive, pyhive

I am trying to access Hive thru Pyhive. I don't want to hardcode HiveServer2 host details in the application code. Is there any way for Pyhive to pick up the details from hive-site.xml?

Or In general, Is there any better client than Pyhive which can get details from hive-site.xml and perform hive operations?